# "Intent must not be null" when sending strings from one activity to another

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to send two strings from two textViews in one activity to another using intents. However, I'm getting this error when I run the function `load`.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.pdm_2021_i_p1_project1, PID: 18672
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pdm_2021_i_p1_project1/com.example.pdm_2021_i_p1_project1.PlayActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: intent must not be null
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3365)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: intent must not be null
    at com.example.pdm_2021_i_p1_project1.PlayActivity.getWord(PlayActivity.kt:119)
    at com.example.pdm_2021_i_p1_project1.PlayActivity.<init>(PlayActivity.kt:21)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3353)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Here's my code from the activity receiving the strings

```
class PlayActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //Variable Declarations
    private val lives : Int = 4
    private var fails : Int = 0
    private var correctGuesses = mutableSetOf<Char>()
    private var guesses = mutableSetOf<Char>()
    private val word = getWord().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
    private val clue = getClue().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
    private val letters = word.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).toCharArray().toHashSet()
    private val txtArray = arrayOfNulls<TextView>(word.length)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play)
        btnCheck.setOnClickListener{(checkWord())}
        createTxtViews()
        txvClue.text = clue.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)
        txvLives.text = "❤❤❤❤"
    }

    private fun checkWord(){
        val character = txtPlayAddLetter.text.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
        if (txtPlayAddLetter.text.isNotEmpty()){
            if (word.contains(txtPlayAddLetter.text.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT))) {
                correctGuesses.add(character[0])
                guesses.add(character[0])
                txvGuessed.text = guesses.toString().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)
                txvTest.text = letters.toString()
                showLetters()
                txtPlayAddLetter.text.clear()
                checkGameState()
            }
            else
            {
                fails++
                guesses.add(character[0])
                txvGuessed.text = guesses.toString().toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)
                txtPlayAddLetter.text.clear()
                val hearts = txvLives.text.dropLast(1)
                txvLives.text = hearts
                when (fails) {
                    1 -> {frame1.isVisible = false
                        frame2.isVisible = true}
                    2 -> {frame2.isVisible = false
                        frame3.isVisible = true}
                    3 -> {frame3.isVisible = false
                        frame4.isVisible = true}
                    4 -> {frame4.isVisible = false
                        frame5.isVisible = true}}
                if (fails == lives)
                {
                    showDefeat()
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this@PlayActivity, "Please enter a letter :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    private fun showDefeat(){
        val intent = Intent(this, DefeatActivity::class.java)
        finish()
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun showVictory(){
        val intent = Intent(this, VictoryActivity::class.java)
        finish()
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    private fun createTxtViews(){
        val lLayout = findViewById<View>(R.id.txtPlayGuessed) as LinearLayout
        for (i in word.indices) {
            txtArray[i] = TextView(this)
            txtArray[i]?.id = i
            txtArray[i]?.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
            txtArray[i]?.hint = "  _  "
            txtArray[i]?.setHintTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.white))
            txtArray[i]?.textSize = 25F
            lLayout.addView(txtArray[i])
            txtArray[i]?.isVisible = true
        }
    }

    private fun showLetters(){
        val str = txtPlayAddLetter.text.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT)
        for (i in word.indices){
            if (txtPlayAddLetter.text.single().toLowerCase() == word[i]){
                txtArray[i]?.text = "  ".plus(str.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)).plus("  ")
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkGameState(){
        if (correctGuesses == letters){
            showVictory()
            finish()
        }
    }

    fun getWord(): String{
        val bundle=intent.extras
        val setword= bundle?.get("setword")
        return getString(R.string.setwordplay,setword)


    }
    fun getClue(): String{
        val bundle = intent.extras
        val setclue = bundle?.get("setclue")
        return getString(R.string.setwordplay,setclue)
    }}
```

And here's my code from the activity sending the strings

```
    fun load(){
        val intent = Intent(this, PlayActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("setword", editTextTypeAWord.text.toString())
        intent.putExtra("setclue", editTextHint.text.toString())
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Comment: this question doesn't have anything to do with android studio specifically, right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to initialise the `val` with data from Intent. In PlayActivity, the `init{}` block and property initialisations run before `onCreate()`.

To work around this issue you could try:

```kotlin
class PlayActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
       const val ARG_WORD = "word"
       const val ARG_CLUE = "clue"
    }

    private lateinit var word: String
    private lateinit var clue: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        word = intent.getStringExtra(ARG_WORD) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Word was not supplied")
        clue = intent.getStringExtra(ARG_CLUE) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Clue was not supplied")
    }
}
```

Call with:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(this, PlayActivity::class.java).apply { 
  putExtra(PlayActivity.ARG_WORD, "giraffe")
  putExtra(PlayActivity.ARG_CLUE, "long neck")
}
startActivity(intent)
```

Also, remember to refactor other properties that rely on `word` and `clue` to use either functions or getters, otherwise you'll run into `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`.
What using getters does is that every time you call the property the `get()`-portion is calculated. Since you're using the properties after `onCreate()`, your lateinit properties should already have been initialised from the intent you've received!

```kotlin
class PlayActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
       const val ARG_WORD = "word"
       const val ARG_CLUE = "clue"
    }

    private lateinit var word: String
    private lateinit var clue: String

    private val letters: HashSet<Char>
        get() = word.toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT).toCharArray().toHashSet()

    private val txtArray: Array<TextView?>
        get() = arrayOfNulls<TextView>(word.length)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        word = intent.getStringExtra(ARG_WORD) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Word was not supplied")
        clue = intent.getStringExtra(ARG_CLUE) ?: throw IllegalArgumentException("Clue was not supplied")
    }
}
```

I highly recommend you to read this: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html

Answer (score 0):

```
val intent = Intent(this, PlayActivity::class.java).apply {
            putExtra("setword", message)
        }
        startActivity(intent)
```

try this

```
  private fun showVictory(){
    val intent = Intent(this, VictoryActivity::class.java)
    
    startActivity(intent)
      finish()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
          intent?.getStringExtra("setword")  ?: ""
          intent?.getStringExtra("setclue")  ?: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this way**

```
fun getWord(): String{
                val setword= intent.getStringExtra("setword")
                return getString(R.string.setwordplay,setword)
   
       }
       fun getClue(): String{
                val setclue = intent.getStringExtra("setclue")
                return getString(R.string.setwordplay,setclue)
       }}
```